# Calculate avg salary of department from input string

Tags: text-processing, awk

If user inputs the employees details as string and we want the output to display the average salary department wise and the output should be in same order as they appear in the input string.

For example input string:

```
EMP101:Jack:HR:6000#EMP102:Jill:Management:10000#EMP103:Russell:Testing:10000#EMP104:Monica:HR:15000#EMP105:John:Management:25000#EMP106:Ram:Testing:8000#EMP107:Tan:HR:15000#EMP108:Harry:Management:10000
```

Output string:

```
HR:12000#Management:15000#Testing:9000
```

I tried below code:

```
echo "EMP101:Jack:HR:6000#EMP102:Jill:Management:10000#EMP103:Russell:Testing:10000#EMP104:Monica:HR:15000#EMP105:John:Management:25000#EMP106:Ram:Testing:8000#EMP107:Tan:HR:15000#EMP108:Harry:Management:10000" \
| awk 'BEGIN{RS="#"; OFS=FS=":"} {gsub(/"\n$/,"",$5); print $3,$4}' \
| awk -F ":" '{a[$1] += $2} {b[$1] += 1} END{for (i in a) print i, a[i]/b[i]}' \
| tr " " ":" \
| tr "\n" "#";
```

got the output as:

```
:0#Testing:9000#Management:15000#HR:12000
```

This is not what I want and also i am not getting why `:0#` is getting added at the starting of the string . Could anyone please tell me how to achieve this in shell script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another variation on a theme

```
echo 'EMP101:Jack:HR:6000#EMP102:Jill:Management:10000#EMP103:Russell:Testing:10000#EMP104:Monica:HR:15000#EMP105:John:Management:25000#EMP106:Ram:Testing:8000#EMP107:Tan:HR:15000#EMP108:Harry:Management:10000' |
    awk -F'#' '
        # Split into lines at "#"
        {
            for(f=1; f<=NF; f++) {
                print $f;
            }
        }
    ' |
    awk -F: '
        # Record department if unknown. Keep running total and count
        {
            if (!(sum[$3]+0)) { pos[idx++]=$3 };
            sum[$3]+=$4;
            count[$3]++;
        }
        # Output department in order of recording, and calculate average
        END {
            for (idx in pos) {
                dept=pos[idx];
                printf "#%s:%d", dept, sum[dept]/count[dept];
            };
            printf "\n";
        }
    ' |
    cut -c2-
```

Output

```
HR:12000#Management:15000#Testing:9000
```

Comment: `for (idx in pos)` will shuffle the order of depts output. See https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Scanning-an-Array. Less importantly, `print ""` is better  than `print "\n"` as it uses whatever value ORS has instead of hard-coding the value you think/hope ORS has. Possibly less importantly still, all arrays, strings, and fields in awk start at 1, not 0, so you should do the same for user-defined arrays to avoid confusion/bugs later so `pos[idx++]` should be `pos[++idx]`.

Answer (score 2):

Using any `awk` and preserve the order:

```
awk 'BEGIN{ RS="#"; FS=OFS=":" }
   { ($3 in dept)?"":ordrDept[++i]=$3; dept[$3]+=$4; seenDept[$3]++; }
END{ for(o=1; o<=i; o++)
         printf "%s%d%s", ordrDept[o] OFS, 
                          dept[ordrDept[o]]/seenDept[ordrDept[o]], 
                          (i==o)?ORS:RS
}' infile
```

Output:

```
HR:12000#Management:15000#Testing:9000
```

---

We used the *`ordrDept`* array to remember each department order by their order they have been seen.
We used the *`dept`*  array to sum-up each department's total salary.
We used the *`seenDept`* array to remember how many times they have been seen.

at the `END{...}` block, and `i` would be the maximum number of existing department we visited in `ordrDept[++i]=$3`, then we are printing them in the order we visited first by `ordrDept[o]`, then the average salary calculation `total/count` per department and with `(i==o)?ORS:RS` we are controlling the separators.

---

An alternative implementation of the above approach with more meaningful variable names would be (thanks to @EdMorton):

```
BEGIN {
    RS = "#"
    FS = OFS = ":"
}
!($3 in depts2sals) {
    depts[++numDepts] = $3
}
{
    depts2sals[$3] += $4
    depts2cnts[$3]++
}
END {
    for (deptNr=1; deptNr<=numDepts; deptNr++) {
        dept = depts[deptNr]
        sal = depts2sals[dept]
        cnt = depts2cnts[dept]
        avg = sal / cnt
        printf "%s%s%s", dept OFS, avg, (deptNr<numDepts ? RS : ORS)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `:0#` is due to an additional, trailing, empty line in your input / file. Your attempt to remove that fails as you provided the wrong pattern to `gsub(...)` as well as a field that doesn't exist. Correct that, or use an extended `RS` variable. As `awk` on its own is quite powerful, no need to run that stack of pipes; do it in one `awk` only.

Try

```
awk 'BEGIN{ORS="#"; RS="[#\n]"; OFS=FS=":"} {SUM[$3]+=$4;CNT[$3]++} END{for (s in SUM) print s, SUM[s]/CNT[s]} ' file3
Management:15000#Testing:9000#HR:12000#
```

Removing the trailing ORS is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: question is asked to preserve the order; also output has an extra trailing `#`; additionally using RS with more than a single character require GNU awk

Answer (score 0):

Here is one method using **perl** .

```bsh
echo 'your-string' |
perl -lnse 'while ( /:([^:#]+):(\d+)(?=#|$)/g )
{
  my @A = ($2,1);
  exists $s{$1} or $D[@D]=$1;
  $_->{$1} += shift(@A) for \(%s,%k);
}
print map { join(":", $_, $s{$_}/$k{$_}) } @D;
' -- -,=\#
```

The data structures involved:

- hash %s keyed on department holds corresponding sum of salaries of employees from the same department.
- hash %k keyed on department holds the number of employees in that department.
- array @D contains the department in the order they were encountered, without repeating.

---

Below is a method taken from your attempt

```bsh
echo 'your_string' |
tr '#' '\n' |
awk -F: '{print $3, NR, $4}' |
sort -k1 -k2n |
awk '
prev != $1 {
  if (NR > 1) print prev, sum/knt
  knt=sum=0;prev=$1
}
{ knt++; sum += $3 }
END { ORS=RS; print prev, sum/knt }
' OFS=: ORS=\#
```

---

GNU sed approach is given. The idea is to collect together same department and space separate the salaries within same department.

```bsh
## dc code to compute average of a list of numbers
avg='[+z1<a]sa\3zsnlaxln/f'

echo 'your_string' |
sed -Ee '
  y/#/\n/
  s/^([^:]*:){2}//Mg;ta
  :a
  s/((^|\n)([^:]+):([0-9]+( [0-9]+)?))(\n(.*\n)?)\3:([0-9]+)(\n|$)/\1 \8\6/
  ta
  :b'"
  s#^((.*\n)?[^:]+:)([0-9]+( [0-9]+)+)((\n.*)?)#printf %s '\\1' \"\$(echo '$avg'|dc)\" '\\5'#e
  tb
  y/\n/#/
"
```